# Solving for fluid velocity field given positions as a function of time

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, computational-physics, flow, differential-equations

I have a distribution function that describes the number of particles as a function of time and their mass, $n(M,t)$, which I can calculate analytically for all $M,t$.  I want to know the evolution of particle masses, which is a smooth function $\dot{m}(M,t)$.  The total number of particles is conserved.  Intuitively, it seems like enough information is provided to find a solution.  I think the situation is perfectly analogous to a fluid, with some density $\rho(x, t)$ which I can find analytically, and need to find the velocity field $v(x, t)$.

I can write the continuity equation as,
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial M}\left[ n \frac{\partial M}{\partial t}\right] = 0.$$
Further, because I have an analytic expression for $n(M,t)$, I know this can be expressed as,
$$A(M) + B(M,t) \cdot v(M,t) + \frac{\partial v(M,t)}{\partial M} = 0,$$
where  $v\equiv \frac{\partial M}{\partial t}$, and $A$ and $B$ are functions that I can calculate (but are a bit ugly to write down).

This looks like something that I can calculate numerically by discretizing $v$, except that I don't have any boundary condition.  If I knew $v(M_0, t)$ then I could find $v(M_1,t)$ and then $v(M_2,t)$ ... but I don't know anything about $v$.  Are there enough constraints to solve the problem?  Do I need additional assumptions (e.g. on the smoothness of $v$)?  Is there an iterative method to find a solution?

Comment: As you mentioned in the problem, you want to know the evolution of the particle masses. I will explain why you need an extra step via some analogy with the energy distribution function of electrons in a plasma, $f_{\rm e}(\vec r,\vec v,t)$. We know the density of electrons is related to $f_{\rm e}(\vec r,\vec v,t)$ via $n_{\rm e}(\vec r,t)=\int_{\vec v}f_{\rm e}(\vec r,\vec v,t)d\vec v$. Now in your case $n(M,t)dM$ denotes the number of particles with mass in the $[M,M+dM]$ range at time $t$. Does this agree with the definition of $n(M,t)$?

Comment: My other question: Is $m$ the total mass of the system?

Comment: @Newbie I *think* $n(M,t)$ can be any conserved quantity, but in my particular case: yes it is the number (actual volumetric number density) per unit mass, i.e. $n=(1/V)dN/dM$ for some fixed volume $V$.  $m$ is the mass of each particle, which I'm considering as the mass of a "parcel" of particles --- perfectly analogous to a position $x$ for a fluid: we can treat $x$ as the fixed coordinates (e.g. when writing $\partial/\partial x$) but we can also use it to refer to the changing position of a parcel of the fluid (e.g. when we write $v = \partial x / \partial t$).

Comment: Similar to my first comment I'm gonna use $f(\vec r,M,t)$ for the density of particles per unit mass at time $t$, i.e., number of particles per unit volume per unit mass at $t$. Thus, $n(\vec r,t)=\int_{M}f(\vec r,M,t)dM$ denotes density of the particles (i.e., number of particles per unit volume at time $t$).

Comment: Similar to the Boltzmann equation for the energy distribution function, this is the equation I obtain for $f(\vec r,M,t)$: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\vec v\cdot \nabla_{\vec r}f+\frac{\partial f}{\partial M}\frac{\partial M}{\partial t}=0$ and for a homogeneous media $f(\vec r,M,t)=f(M,t)$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial M}\frac{\partial M}{\partial t}=0$. The right hand side is 0 since there are no source or sink processes (i.e., collisions). Can you please add the expression for $\frac{\partial M}{\partial t}$ and $f(M,t)$ to the question?